# A medalha "Generalista" está funcionando aqui?

Tags: suporte, medalhas

Há mais ou menos 1 mês percebi (com ajuda [dessa query no Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/221102/generalist-badge-progress-toward-with-improved-sort)) que eu já possuía as condições necessárias pra medalha ["Generalista"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist) (pelo menos 15 pontos em 20 das 40 principais tags). Aguardei um tempo - sabendo que ela não é concedida imediatamente - mas até agora nada. Percebo também que ninguém mais no site a recebeu também (pelo menos mais um usuário - [utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz) - já possui os critérios pra ela).

Essa medalha é condecida com menos frequência que uma vez por mês? Ou há algum problema com ela, ou talvez comigo? (vai que a conta no Data Explorer está errada, talvez levando em conta *community wiki* quando não deveria levar, etc)

Comment: As 40 principais tags precisam ter pelo menos 200 perguntas cada. Deve ser isso. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/167534

Comment: @bfavaretto Entendi. Quer postar isso como resposta, ou será que eu removo a pergunta?

Comment: Acho boa a pergunta, depois elaboro uma resposta.

Comment: A pergunta é boa msm, e a resposta tb.

Comment: Update: missão cumprida, parabéns! :)